# What happens when I change data at shared library?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I have some shared libraries mapped into virtual address space of my task. What happens when I change some data for example in .bss section? I do it using `kmap` with physical page address as argument. I can suggest 2 ways. Data is changed and it influences at all tasks which use the library or the certain page is copied due to COW.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's neither. The .bss area is set up when the executable is loaded. Virtual memory space is allocated for it at that time, and that space won't be shared with any other task. Pages won't be allocated initially (by default, mlock* can change that); they will be faulted in (i.e. demand-zeroed) as referenced.

I think that even if the process forks before touching the memory, the new process would then just get the equivalent (same virtual memory space marked as demand-zero).

So if you already have a physical address for it, I would think that's already happened and you won't be changing anything except the one page belonging to the current process.